# How to automate Login api using RestAssured Framework in testng

Tags: java, api, automation, rest-assured

I am trying to automate simple login API using parameters username and password in rest assured framework.
Following is the code i am using.

```
@BeforeClass
  public void setBaseUri() {          
     RestAssured.baseURI = "https://XXXXXXXX.com";    
}

@Test   
  public void postString () {        
    given().params("password","XXXX").
    .params("username","XXXX")
    .when ()
    .contentType (ContentType.JSON)
    .post ("/login")
    .then().statusCode(200).log().all();
  }
```

Which check for status code 200 and logs the response. When i run the test it shows up error 415 unsupported media. I am not sure whether this code will automate login api. I tried searching on internet but nothing worked.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: is username and password sent as json?

Comment: yes. It is sent as json

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending username and password as json, then you need to use the `.body()` method. Something like this should work:

```
@Test   
public void postString () {
    Map<String, Object> jsonAsMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonAsMap.put("username", "hello");
    jsonAsMap.put("password", "w0rld!");  

    given().
        contentType("application/json").
        body(jsonAsMap).
        when().
        post("/login").
    .then().statusCode(200).log().all();
}
```

In the above example, when you specify the content type, Rest Assured will try to convert the request body to json. There are other ways to set up json POST body [(request body)](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#request-body). For me in particular, I serialize objects in my project instead of creating hashmaps as in the example above. [serialize objects](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#serialization)
What you were doing initially was setting username and password as a query string.

Comment: [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.util.HashMap" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation] this is error i am facing

Comment: what version of rest-assured are you using?

Comment: rest assured 3.0.3